# How to use Blpop using redigo library

Tags: go, redis

I am using **github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis** library.

LPOP is working:

```
Queue := "queue1"
conn.Do("LPOP", Queue)
```

How can I use Blpop with multiple queues(Dynamic array, read from config file)

```
var QueueArray []string
QueueArray[0] = "q1"  
QueueArray[1] = "q2"
conn.Do("BLPOP", QueueArray,0)
```

This does not fetch any record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each list is a separate argument to the BLPOP command.

Use one function argument for each Redis argument with the Redigo client.

```
resp, err = conn.Do(“BLPOP”, “q1”, “q2”, 0)
```

Use redis.Args to create an argument list from an a slice:

```
resp, err := c.Do("BLPOP", redis.Args{}.AddFlat(QueueArray).Add(0)...)
```

Comment: Thanks @MuffinTop for answering. But, I want to pass this QueueArray dynamically.

Comment: @Sumit Edit the question to state the requirement and read the updated answer.